# Taking a leave during probation period?

Tags: vacation, probation, leave

Is it alright to take 1-2 days leave if you are still on probation? I would almost be 3 months in the company during this period but this trip I'm planning is 2 weeks earlier than the end of my probation period. And I cannot move the date.

How do I negotiate with our HR about this? I'm willing to be unpaid during this 1-2 days leave.

Comment: Is this a job offer that you have already accepted?  Or are you already working there?  And how does this question differ from your earlier question http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/how-to-go-on-leave-just-after-joining-a-company which seems to have much more detail?

Comment: ***Ask your manager***. They must approve ***any*** leave, in most countries.

Comment: @JustinCave This is a separate question / separate leave. I've already been accepted by the company. Now, my status is on probation.

Comment: VTC ask your hr department.

Comment: Do you have any earned vacation / sick leave during the probation period. Some do because in some situations probation lasts 2 years.

Answer (score 2):

Thats entirely dependant on your HR department. In most cases, this won't be an issue. But they absolutely have the right to refuse (if they so wish) to grant leave during probation (at least that goes for all countries I know the stance on this of, your mileage may vary).

But honestly, just talk to your HR department. Lay out to them why you want the leave, and barring any serious business reasons, it shouldn't be a problem.

The earlier you do this, the better. Companies usually prefer plenty of notice on when an employee is taking time off.

Comment: They can not refuse vacation completely during the probation period in Germany.